# How can I get the users for a twitter Query in R?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using the twitter package in R, and when I do a searchTwitter I don't know how to get the users of the query..
this is the sentence I am using:

```
searchResults <- searchTwitter('test', n=10)
```

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data that is returned from Twitter via the searchTwitter Function is a list of [status](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/twitter/docs/status) objects. Essentially it can be treated as a list of lists. The first list is all the status objects, the objects in turn can be treated like lists themselves and be indexed/subsetted/accessed the same way using the `$` like so:

```
searchResults[[1]]      # First status object
searchResults[[1]]$text # text of the first status
```

if you want to access the data of all the statuses at once you can use sapply:

```
sapply(searchResults, function(x) x$screenName)
```

of course you can then replace `screenName` with the name of the part of the status object you desire to access.